# Excel VBA Next without For error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a "Next Without for Error on the following code:

```
sub test()
  numRows = 11
  For i = 0 To numRows
    If Cells(i + 1, 2) >= 0 Then
        Range((Cells(A, i + 1)), Cells(B, i + 1)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("PasteLocation").Activate
        Range("Ai+1").Select
        Selection.Paste
  Next
End Sub
```

I assume that my "If" statement doesnt know that it's done and that the "Next" command thinks there should be another nested "for" in the "if" statement but I do not know where.

Comment: You should close your `If` with `End If`. [If then Else Excel VBA - "End If" needed?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37564915)

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: What does this do? `Range("Ai+1").Select`

Comment: "I assume that my 'If' statement doesn't know that it's done" - precisely: you begin an `If` block but never terminate it - hence the compiler "thinks" `Next` is part of the `If` block, can't find a corresponding `For` statement, and blows up saying exactly that: there's a `Next` statement that shouldn't be there. All block syntax work the same way, and they can't be intertwined (i.e. you can't start a `For` loop, begin an `If` block, then close the `For` loop with a `Next`, and then somewhere further down close the `If` block with `End If`)

Comment: There should be questions that result interesting and useful for this community and this could be avoided by checking the code 2 more seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the first comment under my original question by user [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp)

> You should close your If with End If. If then Else Excel VBA - "End If" needed?

Answer (score 3):

As commented, you need `End IF`, but I also made some slight improvements:

```
Sub test()
numRows = 11
For i = 0 To numRows
    If Cells(i + 1, 2) >= 0 Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range(.Cells(1, i + 1), .Cells(2, i + 1)).Copy
        End With
        Sheets("PasteLocation").Range("A" & i + 1).Paste
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Note:** Change `Sheets("Sheet1")` to the appropriate sheet name.